# Как внедрить файлы в ресурсы программы

Tags: c#, resources

Внедрил три текстовых файла в проект. Думал они все время будут в проекте, однако они ссылаются на файлы в папке *debug*, что не есть хорошо, так как если этих файлов нет на диске - то и при компиляции возникают ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Они ссылаются на файлы в папке debug» — непонятно. Кто на кого ссылается?

Comment: они ссылаются на файлы которые есть физически на компьютере. А мне нужно чтобы они были внедрены в сам проект.\

Comment: Кто такие «они»?

Comment: что показано на скриншоте и как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Как я понял, он хочет, что бы файлы были вшиты в программу и на стороне клиента не было в них нужны. @Grundy, а как ты ссылаешь на файле в коде? Мне казалось, что VS по умолчанию их в код зашивает.

Comment: @iluxa1810, это зависит от настройки build action для файла. Я никак не ссылаюсь - нет нужды в этом :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь со статьей на MSDN: [Добавление и редактирование ресурсов (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Для добавления ресурсов в проект необходимо щелкнуть правой кнопкой мыши узел ***Свойства*** в проекте в ***Обозревателе решений***, щелкнуть ***Открыть***, а затем на странице ***Ресурсы*** в ***Конструкторе проектов*** нажать кнопку
***Добавить ресурс***. Ресурсы можно добавить в проект в качестве связанных ресурсов (внешние файлы) или как внедренные ресурсы (внедренные непосредственно в файл **RESX**).

- При добавлении связанного ресурса в файле **RESX** со сведениями о    ресурсах проекта будет указан только относительный путь на файл    ресурса на диске. Если в качестве связанных ресурсов добавить    изображения, видео или другие сложные файлы, их можно будет изменять   в редакторе по умолчанию, сопоставленном с соответствующим типом    файла в конструкторе ресурсов.
- В случае внедренных ресурсов, данные хранятся непосредственно в файле    ресурсов проекта (**RESX**). Строки могут храниться только как внедренные    ресурсы.

После добавления файлов в ресурсы, добавленные файлы помещаются в папку **Resources**, находящуюся в корне проекта.

Также можно задать действие при построении:

- **None** — файл не включается в выходную группу проекта и не
  компилируется в процессе построения. Примером такого файла является
  текстовый файл документации, например файл Readme.
- **Compile** — файл компилируется в выходные файлы построения. Эта
  настройка используется для файлов кода.
- **Content** — файл не компилируется, но включается в выходную группу
  "Содержимое". Этот вариант используется по умолчанию для файлов HTM и
  других веб-файлов.
- **Embedded Resource** — файл внедряется в основные выходные файлы
  построения проекта в виде DLL или исполняемого файла. Обычно это
  значение используется для файлов ресурсов.

Для задания свойства *Действие при построении (`Build Action`)* или свойства *Копировать в выходной каталог(`Copy to Output Directory`)* необходимо зайти в свойства у файла ресурсов и изменить необходимое свойство.

Собственно говоря, Вас интересует свойство *Действие при построении (`Build Action`)* - которое необходимо указать под Ваши нужды.

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

1. [Свойства файла](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Связанные и внедренные ресурсы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ht9h2dk8(v=vs.90).aspx)
3. [Ресурсы в файле формата .Resx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ekyft91f(v=vs.90).aspx)
4. [Ресурсы в приложениях](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f45fce5x(v=vs.90).aspx)
5. [Упаковка и развертывание ресурсов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sb6a8618(v=vs.90).aspx)