# Как добавить exe файл в ресурсы проекта, C# windowd forms

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

Я бы хотел внутрь проекта добавить exe файл, чтобы по нажатии кнопку запустить exe файл который будет внутри моей программы

Но я не знаю как добавить туда exe?

И как его запускать?

я подозреваю это делается так:

```
Process.Start("program.exe");
```

Я подозреваю это делается как-то через ресурсы

[image: Пример]

Comment: В ресурсы можно положить любой файл, но запустить без физического присутствия файла на диске не получится, ограничение ОС. То есть перед запуском файл нужно будет сохранить на диск, и только потом запустить уже известным вам способом.

Comment: @aepot как тогда его с ресурсов на диск перенести?

Comment: [Вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031778/how-can-i-extract-a-file-from-an-embedded-resource-and-save-it-to-disk)

Comment: @aepot а можно ссылку еще как положить в проект именно exe файл, если вы знаете

Comment: А поискать совсем не умеете? Учитесь искать самостоятельно. [Вот ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566707/373567)