# Сохранение файла в папке Debug

Tags: c#

У меня есть файл txt, который обрабатывается в программе, причём программу я заливаю на гит без папок bin and obj, как при этом мне организовать хранение этого файла, как это делается обычно? У меня есть догадки, что я например положу этот файл в директорию с приложением и буду выполнять поиск файла по имени, то есть в консоли напишу название файла и программа найдёт его по имени. В общем подскажите кто и как бы сделал идеи какие-то или может есть канонные решения? Ещё раз скажу, что bin, obj в проекте не будет до запуска, то есть на самом гите, а где этот файл необходимо хранить? Может после запуска приложения нужно этот файл скопировать в папку bin?

Comment: Как вариант смотрите есть ли такой файл рядом с бинарником, если нет то копируете из ресурсов подготовленный шаблон файла. Т.е идея хранить ваш файл в ресурсах самого приложения. и распаковывать его при первом запуске. Сам ресурс спокойно держите в проекте по любому пути. Такой совет валидный?

Comment: [VS2010 How to include files in project, to copy them to build output directory automatically during build or publish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4596508/312041)

Comment: [Как внедрить файлы в ресурсы программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566684/179763)

Comment: У Атема более презентабельный пример

Comment: `bin` - это директория, в которой храниться по умолчанию собранный проект, ее и не должно быть. То есть, тот, кто будет работать с вашим исходным кодом, должен будет его собрать, у него тогда появиться директория `bin`, и если в этой директории нужен отдельный файл, то просто добавтьте его в проект и установите копирование при успешной сборке (первая ссылка от tym32167, все, этого вам будет достаточно. Если же вы хотите, чтоб этот файл создавался при первом запуске вашего приложения, то определитесь с тем, где этот файл должен храниться (сервер, .exe, или др.) и уже на основе этого думайте.