# Развёртывание WindowsForms приложения на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Суть вопроса в том, чтобы развернуть десктопное приложение WindowsForms на языке c# в единый .exe файл.
при использовании "публикации" Visual Studio 2022 развертывается в несколько файлов: Setup.exe, App.application, а также папка Application files.

Имеется проект, использующий внешние .txt файлы. Необходимо завернуть его в один (если это представляется возможным) самостоятельный .exe файл, доступный для запуска на любом компьютере, использующий текстовые файлы, указанные при написании кода.

Вопрос: как создать .exe файл, представляющий из себя самостоятельное приложение, которое также может использовать внешние файлы, используемые программой?

Внешние файлы включаются путём добавления папки с файлами в проект в Visual Studio.
[image: структура проекта]

Здесь программа в Form1.cs берёт входные файлы из папки examples.

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: вы описали задачу, но не вопрос

Comment: @ZxNuClear исправил

Comment: `развертывается в несколько файлов` - наверно потому, что вы выбрали `ClickOnce` тип публикации? Выбирайте публикацию в папку, настраивайте как вам надо, и получайте нужный результат. Если это .NET Framework, то там объединение иначе работает, так что, тут надо еще смотреть и на то, на чем базируется проект. А вообще, [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468942/220553).

Comment: Версию .NET укажете? Суть проблемы не ясна. Почему этот вопрос возник? Вы не можете собрать приложение, или оно после сборки не работает? Или после копирования не работает? Как задаются пути к файлам? Где файлы лежат? Как вы к ним обращаетесь? Что при этом происходит?

Comment: @aepot обновил вопрос, надеюсь стало понятнее. Прошу сильно палками не бить, я в сфере написания десктопных приложений абсолютный новичок.

Comment: Данные в ресурсы, библиотеки смержить с помощью ILMerge. 4.x - старый фреймворк, однофайловую публикацию не поддерживал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/566684/373567

Comment: @aepot что-то поделал, помогло - теперь файл .exe работает самостоятельно, но всё ещё требует файлы ресурсов, как Вы и писали. Попутный вопрос - что необходимо сделать в моём случае, чтобы всё-таки уместить все файлы в один .exe файл?